# How to write a Data Generator for a Keras model using multiple inputs

Tags: r, input, keras, generator

I need some help with getting a Keras model working in RStudio. The problem arises when I have multiple inputs, and use a data generator.

Keras reports an input error. The numpy arrays passed to the model are not what it was expecting.

The following toy example reproduces the problem. When the model is fitted normally (no data generator) it runs OK, but when fitted with a generator it crashes.

## Set up data

```
library(magrittr)
library(keras)

# Create 10 examples of input data and 10 labels

input1 <- matrix(1:20,  ncol=2, nrow=10, byrow=T)   # [1,2; 3,4; 5,6 ... 19,20]
input2 <- matrix(1:30,  ncol=3, nrow=10, byrow=T)    # [1,2,3; 4,5,6 5,6,7 ... 28,29,30]
labels <- seq(0.1,1,0.1)                            # [0,1,0.2,0.3 ... 1.0]
```

## Build & Run Model

```
# define input tensors for the two inputs
in_a <- layer_input(shape = c(2), name = "input1")
in_b <- layer_input(shape = c(3), name = "input2")

# concatenate the inputs and follow them by an output layer
out <- layer_concatenate(c(in_a, in_b), axis=-1, name="concat") %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear', name="output")

# build the model
model <- keras_model(inputs = list(in_a, in_b), outputs = out)

#compile & run
model %>% compile(loss = "mse", optimizer = "adam")
model %>% fit(list(input1, input2), labels, epochs = 5)
```

## Model with generator

```
# The generator will alternatively select the first five input rows and then the second five ad infinitum
data_sample_generator <- function(input1, input2, labels) {

  first_five <- 1

  function() {

    first_five <<- ifelse(first_five == 0,1,0)

    if (first_five==0) {
      rows_to_return <- 1:5 }
    else {
      rows_to_return <- 6:10
    }
  return(list(input1[rows_to_return, ], input2[rows_to_return, ], labels[rows_to_return])) 
    }


}
# Examine generator output
batch <- data_sample_generator(input1, input2, labels)
batch()

# Examine generator output
batch <- data_sample_generator(input1, input2, labels)
```

```
batch()    # first sample
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    5    6
[4,]    7    8
[5,]    9   10

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
[4,]   10   11   12
[5,]   13   14   15

[[3]]
[1] 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5
```

```
batch()    # second sample
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   12
[2,]   13   14
[3,]   15   16
[4,]   17   18
[5,]   19   20

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   16   17   18
[2,]   19   20   21
[3,]   22   23   24
[4,]   25   26   27
[5,]   28   29   30

[[3]]
[1] 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
```

That's what I would have expected to see from the generator. Now to fit the model.

```
model %>% 
  fit_generator(data_sample_generator(input1,input2,labels),
                steps_per_epoch = 2,
                epochs = 5)
```

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :   
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that  
you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.   
Expected to see 2 array(s),   
but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: 
[array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]])]...
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. How can I fix the generator to provide the right shaped inputs? Thanks for any help.

## Modify generator output

As @OIDor suggested, change output to return ([input1, input2], labels)

```
return(list(list(input1[rows_to_return, ], input2[rows_to_return, ]), labels[rows_to_return]))
```

Generator returns

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    5    6
[4,]    7    8
[5,]    9   10

[[1]][[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
[4,]   10   11   12
[5,]   13   14   15

[[2]]
[1] 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5
```

This time, I get the error message ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,2) into shape (5)

Answer (score 1):

Generator should return a tuple2d:

```
 (X, y)
```

In your case X is a list of arrays, so it becomes:

```
([X1, X2], y)
```

Your generator yields:

```
list(input1[rows_to_return, ], input2[rows_to_return, ], labels[rows_to_return])
```

which is equivalent to:

```
([X1, X2, y])
```

I don't know `R`, but I think you should change your generator to this:

```
list(input1[rows_to_return, ], input2[rows_to_return, ]), labels[rows_to_return]
```

**UPDATE:**

Now that you have updated your code, the Input shapes you pass to your model are:

1st input: (5, 2)

2nd input: (5, 3)

output: (5)

Keras error suggests that your model expects to see 1st input as (for example):

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

while you are passing:

```
[[1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]
```

So you should either change your batch generator, or the model's Input shape

Comment: Thanks @OIDor. I see the problem. I tried your suggestion (see edits.)  but now I'm getting the error message "cannot broadcast input array from shape (5,2) into shape (5)".

Comment: Thanks @OIDor. I will try it out.